# Node http-proxy and express

Tags: node.js, express, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
// Setup prox to handle blog requests
httpProxy.createServer({
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        'http://localhost': '8080',
        'http://localhost/blog': '2368' 
    }
}).listen(8000);
```

Previously I was using this:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Basically, I want to still use express... but, when people go to `http://localhost/blog` get taken to the blog but still be served over `port 8080` (which will eventually be port 80)

So I switched it to this and it worked better. The problem is that express takes over the routing (from what I can tell)

```
var options = {
    // pathnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        'localhost': 'localhost:8080',
        'localhost/blog': 'localhost:2368'
    }
}

// Setup prox to handle blog requests
var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);
proxyServer.listen(9000);

require('./app/server/router')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: When they go to `/blog` I want it to run my Ghost app that hosts my blog... otherwise, run my normal site.

Comment: Struggling in similar kind of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323332/node-calling-rest-web-services-behind-a-corporate-proxy can you suggest me if you have any solution

Answer (score 44):

Using http-proxy 1.0 with express:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.get("/api/*", function(req, res){ 
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://google.com:80' });
});
```

Comment: Hello Chandler, this seems to work when no cookies are involved. Do you know how can I make the sessions work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can this be generalized to other http verbs such as post\put\delete?

Comment: @Lucas:
As of my knowledge, proxies won't work with cookies. Cookies are not sent to the same origin. unless you rewrite the cookie domain/paths too.
I suggest you to try out token based approach. JWT

Comment: hi, @Chandler. In your answer, the request would be proxied to http://google.com:80/api/*, is it possible to proxy to a different path on the target server? e.g http://google.com/some_diffrent_service/xxx/yyy.

Comment: Possible to just add http_proxy as middleware to express?

Answer (score 9):

A very straightforward solution which works seamlessly, and with cookies/authentication as well, using `express-http-proxy`:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

var blogProxy = proxy('localhost/blog:2368', {
    forwardPath: function (req, res) {
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
});
```

And then simply:

```
app.use("/blog/*", blogProxy);
```

I know I'm late to join this party, but I hope this helps someone.

Comment: When I use proxy with a port (in my case, 5000), and have the app running on port 8050, the proxy still proxies out on port 8050.  My code looks like this  proxy('core-api:5000', { /* calculate forward path */ }).  Did you test the above code, and what port is node hosting on?

Comment: @Lo-Tan - Yes, this is working code from a personal server of mine. Note you don't have the `localhost/` prefix showing in the answer. My main express app is listening on port 80.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking the proxy URL should show up in chrome developer tools.  Doh  ><  I had another issue instead (bad url path after the host)  It works fine :)  Thanks!

Comment: @Lo-Tan - Happy to help. :)

Comment: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.co.in www.google.co.in:80
   at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)


Getting the above mentioned error. Any idea?

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez Yup. `www.google.com`, `http://www.google.com` and `https://www.google.com` yields the same

Comment: I assume this is Google, not trusting your proxy. Which does make sense. Why would you proxy Google?

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez Not Google exactly. Just used google to check this.

Comment: This may work well for non-https requests. However, there's no options for configuring secure certs/keys. If you need https, then I'd suggest using http-proxy.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working.

- [Install Ghost](http://docs.ghost.org/installation/) and make sure it's working property (default port is 2368)
- Create your node web app using express (listen on port 80) - nothing special here
- Install [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) `npm install http-proxy` in your web app
- Create wildcard route for /blog* that proxies requests to Ghost service

  ```
  var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

  var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
  app.get('/blog*', function (req, res, next) {
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res ,{
      host: 'moserlap.splitvr.com',
      port: 2368  
    });
  });
  ```
- Update the Ghost config to use a sub directory (only supported in 0.4.0+)

  ```
  config = {
    // ### Development **(default)**
    development: {
    // The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and email.
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/blog',
  ...
  ```
- You should now be able to hit http://yoursite.com/blog and all routes work.

Comment: This answer doesn't work with http-proxy 1.0, httpProxy.RoutingProxy is no longer a method. 

see my answer for an update

Answer (score 2):

I have used simple solution to proxified my GET/POST requests.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.post("/api/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:5000'})
});
app.get("/api/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:5000'})
});
```

another easier way to handle all type of requests is:

```
app.all("/api/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:5000'})
});
```

NOTE: above functions must be before **bodyparser**.