# Ajax request from another domain using AngularJs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular-http, deployd

I'm using this book to learn AngularJS where I build this webapp with Angular, Node, Deployd. Now, my app stays at localhost:5000/app.html, 5000 is the port where node web server listen. I try to retrieve my data stored with deployd in this way:

```
$http.get("localhost:5500/products")
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.data.products = data;
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.data.error = error;
    });
```

But this cause an error: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. How can I solve this? Thanks :)

Comment: Read the error message a bit more. doesn't it say something about a same origin policy? Did you research what the same origin policy is? There's very little that you can do with angularjs to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, I think it's not the same origin cause the port is different. But I can't solve this. Also, I'm working in local so I didn't expect these sort of issues.

Comment: it gives me the same error with google chrome, but not with safari and firefox, to disable it in google chrome ->


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: No, it definitely is the same origin issue. different port means different origin.

Comment: @ThomasP1988 how did you instruct your users to do the same after you release the application to the public?

Comment: Yes, I know but in the book the author not mention this. It's like he didn't have this issue.

Comment: Likely because he's using the same origin for both api and web client. same port protocol and domain.

Comment: If he isn't, then his api (or service) is correctly implementing CORS to satisfy the same origin policy.

Comment: Uh, my problem is the same of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346863/deployd-data-retrieved-via-angularjs-cors?rq=1

Comment: Which book are you reading?  If it's Pro AngularJS, I posted a solution to that problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346863/deployd-data-retrieved-via-angularjs-cors/23434583#23434583  The solution is to upgrade your deployd server.  The more recent version of the deployd server adds the CORS headers, thus you do not get that error anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Kevin B is right. It's the Same Origin Policy blocking your request.

What you should do here is to direct your requests from the client to your node server ("/products"). Here, you can easily proxy them to localhost:5500, e.g. using node-http-proxy (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

From the node-http-proxy README.md (adapted the host/port to your use-case):

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options);
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:5500' });
});
```

It might be, that this interferes with your current node server (serving you the client-side angular code in the first place). In case you're using Express for this, you can combine "http" and "http-proxy" like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244101/3651406

Comment: var connect = require('connect'); 
var serveStatic = require('serve-static'); 
var app = connect(); 
app.use(serveStatic('../angularjs'));
app.listen(5000);

This is my server. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: put this in between app.use(...) and app.listen(...): app.get("/deployd/*", function(req, res){ 
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:5500' });
}); Then you have to change the request in your client to go to "/deployd/products"